# Alias: `git pop last`, for `git stash pop [last stash on the list]`

Tags: git, git-stash

Is this even possible? I want an easier command to `git stash pop stash@{13}` where `stash@{13}` would simply be `last` meaning "the last stash on the list" or "the oldest stash".

I know I can create an alias of `git pop` for `git stash pop` (which I could use like `git pop stash@{13}`), but I'd like something simpler like `git pop last`. Would I need to write my own script or is there a way to do it just with git or alias? I use Windows primarily but sometimes Linux.

Comment: You will need to write some code. The stash IDs `stash@{whatever}` are actually just `git reflog` references and are parsed by `git rev-parse` according to the rules in the `gitrevisions` documentation. There is no special syntax for "highest valid number". You can, however, run `git reflog stash` to get a list of all the valid reflog entries for `stash`, and then get the last one (or count them) to find the desired number.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you find yourself frequently using the *oldest* item on the stack (but presumably not any of the others in the middle)?

Comment: Thanks @torek, very helpful; this should be an answer. Xiong, I don't frequently need this, just sometimes if stashes have been sitting there awhile (which does happen in my job circumstances, based on changing priorities or testing), and I just wanted an easier way than running git stash list each time to make sure I got the correct number. Frequency isn't important here, just ease of use is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building off the hints provided by [@torek](//stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek), this should get you the ref of the stash you want:

```
git reflog stash -- 2> /dev/null | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -d ':' -f 1
```

The `--` ensures you are looking for a revision rather than a path. The `2> /dev/null` suppresses errors in case there are no stashes.

An alternative that avoids using `cut` (again suggested by @torek) is:

```
git log --walk-reflogs --format=%gd stash -- 2> /dev/null | tail -n 1
```

Thus, you can set your alias like this:

```
git config alias.pop-last "! git stash pop $(git reflog stash -- 2> /dev/null | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -d ':' -f 1)"
```

Or:

```
git config alias.pop-last "! git stash pop $(git log --walk-reflogs --format=%gd stash -- 2> /dev/null | tail -n 1)"
```

Either of these commands will give you a nice error of `No stash found.` if there is none found.

I've tested and this works in the Git Bash prompt on Windows. (It should also work in Linux.)

Comment: Some minor shortening is possible: `git reflog` is just `git log -g --oneline`, so instead we can use `git log -g --format=%gd stash` to avoid the need for `cut`. I was also thinking one might need to check for no stashes, but we can do that by redirecting stderr to /dev/null: As a sort of weird positive bonus, if there are no stashes, `tail` outputs nothing and `git stash pop` produces a useful error message. :-) I'm not sure if `2> /dev/null` works on Windows though (I avoid Windows).

Comment: Thanks @torek! Updated my answer. I did verify that `2> /dev/null` works on Windows, though I avoid Windows too. :P